# Iteration and TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration, typeerror, keyerror

I am making a stacked bar chart where the x axis is the company name, y axis is the number of calls, and the stacks are the months. The total time period is a year.

I want to be able to use the code to also call a graph for the month, where the stacks are days, and a graph for the week, where the stacks are days. Therefore I am trying to make it more iterable.

In my working code for the year I get the months for the bar chart this way:

```
Jan = pivot_table[1].astype(float).values
Feb = pivot_table[2].astype(float).values
Mar = pivot_table[3].astype(float).values
Apr = pivot_table[4].astype(float).values
May = pivot_table[5].astype(float).values
Jun = pivot_table[6].astype(float).values
Jul = pivot_table[7].astype(float).values
Aug = pivot_table[8].astype(float).values
Sep = pivot_table[9].astype(float).values
Oct = pivot_table[10].astype(float).values
Nov = pivot_table[11].astype(float).values
Dec = pivot_table[12].astype(float).values
```

Then I write the months into an `OrderedDict`

```
months = OrderedDict([('Jan', Jan), ('Feb', Feb), ('Mar', Mar), ('Apr',Apr), ('May',May), ('Jun',Jun),('Jul',Jul), ('Aug',Aug), ('Sep',Sep),('Oct',Oct),('Nov',Nov),('Dec',Dec)])
```

Obviously this is not ideal. Therefore, I wrote a loop instead.

```
months=[]
for month in range(1,12): 
    months[month] = pivot_table[month].astype(float).values
```

This gave an error `IndexError: list assignment index out of range` 
So I looked up the error and found that the ideal method is to append the value into the list. My next step was to try:

```
months=[]
for month in range(1,12): 
    months.append(pivot_table[month].astype(float).values)
```

and change the `OrderedDict` accordingly:

```
months = OrderedDict([('Jan', 1), ('Feb', 2), ('Mar', 3), ('Apr',4), ('May',5), ('Jun',6),('Jul',7), ('Aug',8), ('Sep',9),('Oct',10),('Nov',11),('Dec',12)])
```

This gave the error `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` This seems like an error that people regard as very straightforward, but even after reading through all the stackflow answers I can't figure out how to fix it. I tried enclosing the pivot_table line in [] and [[]] but this didn't work. I also tried doing this:

```
months=[]
for month in str(range(1,12)): 
    months.append(pivot_table[month].astype(float).values)
```

but got this error `KeyError: '['` and if I print months I get an empty list, which makes me think it's not iterating correctly.

Comment: To get the numbers from 1 to 12 (including), you need to use `range(1, 13)` – or alternatively use `range(12)` and add 1 when you use the number.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I changed it to range(1,13). This gives a list from 1 to 12 like I wanted. Still getting this really bizarre key error. I don't think I'm calling a bracket anywhere! All I changed from my working code was this loop section

Comment: Could you include the *full* traceback of the `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` in your question? That version of your code should actually have worked in my opinion.

Comment: @mkrieger1 it seems as though my addition of str() got rid of the typeerror and left me with a new Key Error. I added the traceback

Comment: Ok thanks for that, but I really meant the traceback for the `TypeError`. The addition of `str()` is definitely wrong, because now you don't iterate over the *numbers* 1, 2, 3 etc., but over the *characters* that make up the list in its printed form: `[`, `1`, `,` etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
str(range(1, 12)) == '[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]'
```

and thus

```
for month in str(range(1, 12))
```

will iterate over the *string* and not the array as intended. Try instead

```
for month in range(1, 13):
    months.append(pivot_table[str(month)].astype(float).values)
```

(13 to get the 12:th index included)

Comment: I tried this and now month is an int of value 1, and months is a list of size zero []

Comment: Yes, that is maybe not so unexpected. Is there a reason you want the month variable to be an ordered dict?

Comment: I want it ordered in order to plot it in the right way. I pulled the code from here http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/stacked_bar_chart.html and was just trying to use my own data. If there's a better way I'm up for that though!

Comment: @pingul: how do you know that `pivot_table` must be indexed with `str(month)` instead of `month`?

Comment: @jenryb Then I am not sure what the OrderedDict you use is for. Are you sure your second attempt is not working? I.e.
`for month in range(1, 12):
    months.append(pivot_table[month].astype(float).values`
This for-loop shouldn't crash.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I didn't fully comprehend the whole question, but only really answered why he received the `KeyError`. I agree with your comment above that the code he tested should work.